Error bun run dev (EBUSY: EBUSY watching)
(base) PS D:\devika\ui> bun run dev
$ vite dev
44277 |         sysPath$2.resolve(path, evPath), KEY_LISTENERS, sysPath$2.join(path, evPath)
44278 |       );
44279 |     }
44280 |   };
44281 |   try {
44282 |     return fs$7.watch(path, options, handleEvent);
                   ^
EBUSY: EBUSY watching "D:/devika/ui"
 syscall: "watch"
   path: "D:/devika/ui"

      at new FSWatcher (node:fs:105:27)
      at watch2 (node:fs:284:199)
      at createFsWatchInstance (D:\devika\ui\node_modules\vite\dist\node\chunks\dep-B-u6xNiR.js:44282:12)
      at setFsWatchListener (D:\devika\ui\node_modules\vite\dist\node\chunks\dep-B-u6xNiR.js:44329:15)
      at _watchWithNodeFs (D:\devika\ui\node_modules\vite\dist\node\chunks\dep-B-u6xNiR.js:44484:14)
      at D:\devika\ui\node_modules\vite\dist\node\chunks\dep-B-u6xNiR.js:44720:14
error: script "dev" exited with code 1

Need fix this error, I got this error after try to run bun run dev
I follow this video on YouTube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gcMdzGrDLlw
But stuck on bun run dev.
Any help really appreciate

Update!!!
I able to solve, thank to @CarmeloCampos on bun discord. You just need to install nodejs and success

Problem
Another bun server is running watching a the lockfile bun.lockb preventing other servers to do the same resulting in the error code EBUSY
Solution
Kill all the processes running bun, since you are on windows, u can do so by opening Task manager > Search "bun" and kill all the processes
Then rerun the command and it should work
